# What do I need to know to manage memory in Objective C++?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm working with a C++ audio library in an iPhone app. Is there any Objective C / Cocoa memory management infrastructure I can use for my C++ objects, or do I need to just read up and learn C++ memory management?

Comment: You can write wrappers for the C++ classes, which allocate and free them in the corresponding Objective-C methods (init and dealloc), and then access the library through these wrappers, using the standard Cocoa memory management techniques (even autorelease will work).

Comment: Felixyz: you are correct but would that assume understanding c++ memory management? E.g. what is `new` and `delete` and scope of variables? Would you buy and application from a developer who does not understand basic issue like managing memory? On top of that, if he is objective-c developer it will be easy to understand c++ memory management as it is a subset of functionality objective-c provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [my latest blog post useful](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/3/5/the-80s-called-they-want-their-memory-manager-back.html), at least the first half, as I discuss and compare both Objective-C memory management and idiomatic C++ memory management.

Executive summary is that most C++ devs use [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

With Objective-C++ there are additional things to worry about - in particular the fact that (at least by default), C++ value types held as members of Objective-C classes do not have constructors or destructors called automatically for you. You can call them explicitly, of course - but it's ugly. Personally I tend to just hold them by intrusive pointers (smart, reference counted, pointers where the ref count is held within the object itself - much like Obj-C pointers - which is why they are a good fit).

Comment: Couldn't agree more with your post: "My point is that, because of smart pointers - made possible by deterministic destruction ... garbage collection is not really missed in C++."